# Can you learn from following mailing lists?

Tags: mailing-list

I follow what feels like a lot of mailing lists of libraries that I use and I think that there is a lot to learn by the questions people ask in them. I don't ask many questions in them and I answer some, but not lots of questions that people ask. I try to be the first to answer a question in which I know the answer, it's kind of a game almost. I feel that if I can get to the point where I can answer nearly every question that's asked, I've successfully learned the framework/library/etc.

Does anybody else feel that they've learned from following lists? Is it a waste of time?

Comment: That game sounds a lot like the Stack Overflow game. :)

Comment: I think it's worth discussing, I feel like I do learn, but it's at a snails pace. I'm curious as to what others think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've learned a lot from the Alt.Net mailing list, and my own local user group mailing list.  One note on the local mailing list: not only is it an excellent way to learn new ideas, and keep up with what is going on, it is a great way to find local experts.  People you can have over for a beer (or lesser beverage of choice) to discuss problems.  For more involved issues, that is often the best way to solve them.  I find that you are much more likely to find actual mentorship in these mailing lists as well -- and less RTFM (you don't get that as much when people can find out where you live).

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course.  Reading a mailing list is essentially like being a fly on the wall of the meeting room of the product authors.  How could you not benefit from that kind of exposure :).

Also, at the end of the day you are reading content riddled information about a subject you are interested in.  True it's not a book and the occasional flame war / off topic threads popup.  But it's still reading and interacting on some level with the subject matter you're interested in.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I dont think it is a waste of time, but to learn only by mailling lists without "getting hands on" that is a waste of time(my humild opinion)